# Assign 2 ips to different tomcat webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016

I've created AWS EC2 instance with Windows Server 2016 OS. I want to configure a Java environment with Tomcat server.

**Main target:** assign multiple IPs to same server.

For example on the server runs three server web apps reachable via: 
localhost:80, locahost:81, localhost:82

or via context path: localhost:80/app1, localhost:80/app2, localhost:80/app3

How can I map three different Elastic IPS to this differen webapps?

Answer (score 0):

You can add secondary network interfaces to an instance and you can have multiple IPs attached to the same single instance.

In case you have plans to ensure high availability of your application, you will have to horizontally scale sometime and it would be better to start off with Application Load Balancer in that case. We can have different target groups with instances and based on rule based routing you can forward the request to specific target group at any desired port.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html

Comment: thanks but the main target is how to assign different IPs to differend webaps